# "mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0" is not becoming true

Tags: php, mysql

I have this `php` code sample and I have several rows in the database tables... but the condition (`mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0`) is not satisfying...

```
<?php
    include './Dashboard/database_connect.php';

    if (!empty($_POST['firstName']) && !empty($_POST['lastName'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lname = $_POST['lastName'];

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE firstname='$fname' AND lastname='$lname'");
        $row=  mysqli_num_rows($query);

        echo "<script>alert('1')</script>"; 

        if($row>0){ #this if condition is not becoming true, even if I have multiple rows in my database's patient table

            echo "<script>alert('Rows Found')</script>";

        }else{
           echo "<script>alert('No Rows found')</script>"; 
        }
    } else {

        echo "<script>alert('wrong')</script>";
    }
    ?>
```

Can anyone please Help???

Comment: Check if `mysqli_query` returns without error.

Comment: How can I check that Sir? @RickAstley

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with parameter values.  It leads to syntax errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: First, your code is exposed to SQL Injection! Second, check your query without `WHERE` clause.

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php will tell you if you have an error

Comment: Query is fine sir @IsmailRBOUH

Comment: @chris85: Sir I didn't get that. Can you simplify that for me?

Comment: `if (!$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE firstname='$fname' AND lastname='$lname'")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: Sir, I think the problem is with my include (`'database_connection.php'`). When I use it without including it's working.Is there any particular reason?